# Determine $\cos(\alpha+\theta)$ given $\sin \theta=3/5$ and $\cos \alpha=12/13$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having some trouble with this question. I don't really understand what it is asking.

$\theta$ and $\alpha$ are acute angles in standard position. $\sin\theta=\frac{3}{5}$ and $\cos\alpha=\frac{12}{13}$

What is the exact value of $\cos(\alpha+\theta)$?

I've tried to find a trig identity that will allow us to solve this and haven't had any success.
All Help is appreciated! :)

I'm somewhat familiar with the cosine addition formula.

So far, I have

$\cos(\alpha+\theta) = \cos(\frac{12}{13})\cdot\cos(y)-\sin(\frac{3}{5})\cdot\sin(y)$

I now have

$\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$

$\cos^2\theta=1-\frac{9}{25}$

$\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{16}{25}}$

$\cos\theta=\frac{4}{5}$

Edit:
Thanks to everyone who helped out!
Here is the answer I came up with:

(cont. from above)

$\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta\\\sin^2\theta=1-\frac{144}{169}\\\sqrt{sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{25}{169}}\\\sin\theta=\frac{5}{13}\\\cos(\alpha+\theta)=(\frac{12}{13})(\frac{4}{5})-(\frac{5}{13})(\frac{3}{5})\\\therefore\cos(\alpha+\theta)=\frac{33}{65}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know the cosine addition formula?

Comment: I'm somewhat new to it, but I kind of understand it.

Comment: Then edit your question to include that.  Do you know what $\cos\theta$ is ?

Comment: The cos(x+y)=cosxcosy-sinxsiny? I'm somewhat familar, I just don't understand how to find the sin(y) or the cos(x). I'm assuming that the first part would be cos(12/13)*cos(y)-sin(3/5)*sin(y) but Don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: the pairs $3,4$ and $12, 13$ are each parts of well known right triangles.

Comment: That's correct.  Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4146026/edit) your question to include that.  For the next step, consider that $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate the $cos^{2}(\theta)+\sin^{2)(\theta)=1$

Does it have something to do with taking the square root to get just $sin(\theta)+\sin(\theta)$?

Comment: Judging purely by the title to your question, there is insufficient information
to compute $\cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b)$ because $\cos(b) = \pm(4/5)$ and 
$\sin(a) = \pm(5/13).$  However, your question has indicated that the pertinent
angles (now referred to as $\theta$ and $\alpha$) are both "*acute angles in standard
position*".  This implies that for each of the two angles, both their sine and
cosine functions have positive values.  This makes it **game over**.

Comment: $\sin^2\theta=\frac9{25}\implies \cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta=\frac{16}{25}\implies \cos\theta=\pm\frac4{5}$; and where you wrote $\cos\frac{12}{13}$, you should have written $\frac{12}{13}$  or $\cos\alpha$

Comment: So I just worked it out thanks to @J.W.Tanner the next step I assume is cos((4/5)+(12/13))?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm guessing I now use the cos(x+y)=cosxcosy-sinxsiny formula?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone!
Here is the answer I got:

$\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1\\\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta\\\cos^2\theta=1-(\frac{3}{5})^{2}\\\cos^2\theta=1-\frac{9}{25}\\\sqrt{\cos^{2}\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{16}{25}}\\\cos\theta=\frac{4}{5}$

$\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta\\\sin^2\theta=1-\frac{144}{169}\\\sqrt{sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{25}{169}}\\\sin\theta=\frac{5}{13}\\\cos(\alpha+\theta)=(\frac{12}{13})(\frac{4}{5})-(\frac{5}{13})(\frac{3}{5})\\\therefore\cos(\alpha+\theta)=\frac{33}{65}$

Comment: I think you meant $\sin\color{red}\alpha=\frac5{13}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: All you need to do to finish is to note that we always have $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ (why?)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: using *Pythagoras' identity*, you can determine $|\sin\alpha|$ and $|\cos\theta|$. Can you determine their signs?

Answer (score 0):

Using the cosine addition formula, $\cos(\alpha+\theta)=\cos\alpha\cos\theta-\sin\alpha\sin\theta$.

Using the Pythagorean formula, $\cos\theta=\frac45$ and $\sin\alpha=\frac5{13}$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Would it look something like cos(a+b) = (12/13)*cos(b)-sin(a)*(3/5)?

Comment: Yes, and then figure out values for $\cos b$ and $\sin a$ using the Pythagorean formula